# Sort Datewise through FOR from BATCH file

Tags: batch-file

The requirement is that I have 1 folder and in that folder there are so many **txt files**, and everyday 100s of files landed and processed, now I want to monitor how many files are present on the folder at the moment when I run the bat file for today's date.

Below is the script I have been using, but seems it is working but fetching all the document instead of **today's** document only

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c1=0
    for  /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /s /a /b "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\KEN*.txt" 2^>nul') do set /a c1+=1

echo.KEN,!c5!
```

Comment: Try `dir /s /a "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\*.txt" 2>NUL | find /C "%date%"`

Comment: Giving me error, not working fine

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] instead of useless "_giving me error_", "_not working fine_" or "_not working at all_"  enunciation. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement (and error code/message)  are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @RishabhBhargav, you have completely failed to answer the questions raised as a result of your opening comment to my answer. In your question, please try to explain what, `I don't think i can create a robocopy in the Production, this is working in UAT but not an option for me` is supposed to mean? What are `Production` and `UAT`? and what is stopping you using the `RoboCopy` command?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

---

From the Command prompt:

```bat
(For /F %A In ('Dir/S/W/A-D-S-L "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\NGR*.txt" 2^>Nul') Do @Call Set "fC=%dC%"&Set "dC=%A")&Call Echo(%fC%
```

---

From a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "dC="
For /F %%A In ('Dir/S/W/A-D-S-L "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\NGR*.txt" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "fC=!dC!"&Set "dC=%%A"
Echo %fC%
Pause
```

*You could optionally include `%DATE% @ %TIME%` on line `5` too.*

Comment: I don't think i can create a robocopy in the Production, this is working in UAT but not an option for me

Comment: if you can give me any other option

Comment: If you have important information relevant to your question, I'd suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47013588/edit) your question to include it!

Comment: I have recreated the code above after re-reading your question and seeing a completely different task. Is this now a closer solution?

Comment: I have changed my question and clear my query, hope this may help you to understand and help me out with the query

Answer (score 0):

a convenient command to find files "created today" is the `forfiles` command (not used very often, probably because of its counter-intuitive syntax and some oddities). Pipe it to `find /c` to get the count, put a `for /f` around it and you're done:

```
set "days=0"
REM 0 for "created zero days ago" = "created today"
set count=0
REM for /f %%x in ('forfiles /D %days% /P "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow" /m "KEN*.txt" ^|find /i /c ".txt"') do set count=%%x
echo KEN,%count%
```

set `days` to `3` to get files newer than three days (today and the two days before) - may be useful on Mondays.

("zero days old" means "today" (not the last 24 hours, but since 00:00) - just  one of it's oddities)